# Can I set a function as a default argument?

Tags: python, function, arguments, default-arguments

I have recently found out that a function can be used like this:

```
def func():
    print("Hello World!")


def run_func(name_of_func):
    name_of_func()


run_func(func)  # Prints "Hello World!"
```

A function name is used as an argument. So my question is if a default argument can be used in this situation. More specifically, if `run_func()` is called without an argument, can there be a default argument so my program outputs nothing and ends without raising an error?

There are similar functions like this for scheduling a function and looping it. However, when the function is called, an argument must be put in or it will result in an error (basically there is no default argument).

Comment: Why don't you just try instead of posting a question?

Comment: `can there be a default argument so my program outputs nothing and ends without raising an error?` - the default would need to be [callable](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```py
def func():
    print("Hello World!")


def run_func(name_of_func=func):
    name_of_func()


run_func()  # Prints "Hello World!"
```

It's good to play with things and try them out, sometimes. :)

Comment: Ah, yea. I should have done that. Thanks for answering anyway! I will try to play around with my questions before asking in the future!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

```
def foo(x = 0):
    print(x + 5)

foo(10)
foo()
```

The output will be:
10
5
This is because 0 is the default argument for the function

In your case, you could try the following:

```
def func():
    print("Hello World!")

def run_func(x = func):
    func()
```

Then when you call run_func() without any arguments, so long the function 'func' is actually defined, you won't get any errors.

Hoped this helped.